# Why is my bathroom fan buzzing and humming when I first turn it on?

Tags: electric-motor, fans

It is strange, the bathroom fan is buzzing and humming when I first turn it on. After a few minutes, it starts up normally.

Why is it doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sticky old oil in the bearings. After buzzing (and probably turning very slowly) for a while, the motor heats up enough for the oil to liquify, and then it runs normally.

Try fresh oil if the bearings have a place to apply oil, or consider a new fan. This is a common problem with old fans.

Comment: Last night it stopped and never run again, is it still repairable?

Comment: Sounds like it's time for a new one. You *might* be able to replace the motor, but this usually only makes economic sense when you can't just replace the whole fan for some reason.